# Listing first and second values in a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I know this might be a simple problem for some of you. I am not able to get the output as expected.
The input tensor is given below.

```
X = tensor([[50.7500, 44.0000],
        [47.0000, 47.0000],
        [42.5000, 52.2500],
        [59.6163, 50.7097],
        [54.6682, 54.6682],
        [48.7304, 61.5956],
        [71.3156, 59.5631],
        [64.7864, 64.7864],
        [56.9515, 73.9272]])
```

I want two tensors A and B such that

```
A = tensor([[50.7500],
        [47.0000],
        [42.5000],
        [59.6163],
        [54.6682],
        [48.7304],
        [71.3156],
        [64.7864],
        [56.9515]]) and 
B = tensor([[44.0000],
        [47.0000],
        [52.2500],
        [50.7097],
        [54.6682],
        [61.5956],
        [59.5631],
        [64.7864],
        [73.9272]])
```

This is what I tried till now.

```
idx = torch.LongTensor([0]) 
idx1 = torch.LongTensor([1]) 
A = X.index_select(1,idx)
B = X.index_select(1,idx1)
```

which is not giving me output as expected. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pick elements from second index in the tensor, you can do this as follows:

```
A=X[:,0]
B=X[:,1]
```

The output of this will be :

```
print(B)
>>>tensor([44.0000, 47.0000, 52.2500, 50.7097, 54.6682, 61.5956, 59.5631, 
64.7864, 73.9272])

print(A)                                                                                                                                                               
>>>tensor([50.7500, 47.0000, 42.5000, 59.6163, 54.6682, 48.7304, 
71.3156, 64.7864,56.9515])
```

But since you want two dimensional tensors, you can then do

```
A.unsqueeze(dim=1)
B.unsqueeze(dim=1)
```

In above case you had to explicitly tell which dimension you have to add/unsqueeze but you can avoid that by using list of indexes as below:

```
A = X[:, 0:1]
B = x[:, 1:2]
```

Using indexes of type `i:i+1` will preserve the number dimensions from old tensor.

Comment: @SauravRai Added more details

Answer (score 1):

You can use `torch.split` to split the tensor into tensors of a given length (here: 1) along the desired dimension (here: 1)

```
A, B = X.split(1, dim=1)

A
>>> tensor([[50.7500],
        [47.0000],
        [42.5000],
        [59.6163],
        [54.6682],
        [48.7304],
        [71.3156],
        [64.7864],
        [56.9515]])

B
>>> tensor([[44.0000],
        [47.0000],
        [52.2500],
        [50.7097],
        [54.6682],
        [61.5956],
        [59.5631],
        [64.7864],
        [73.9272]])
```